# htaccess DirectoryIndex not obeying

Tags: .htaccess, directoryindex

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
```

This should use html and then php for the directory index, and it does. But when I manually type index.php in the url, I'm redirected to index.html. Can this be avoided?

If I remove the .htaccess file index.php becomes the default, so I guess the server is readin the instructions but not obeying them as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Check that .htaccess does not exist in a folder before the current folder with different config overruling your current one.
Ensure your host or your apache configuration allows such changes.

Here is another link with some advice:
http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=908206

Hope this helps

Comment: this is in the root, as far as I can tell. searched the server and found no other htaccess files.

Comment: seems like wordpress is interfering. will have to attack this from a different angle. thanks anyway!